# sort qweb report by date

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-10, qweb

I want to sort the customer statement report in odoo 10 by date or due date.

In odoo 10 community after selecting a Given Customer, you will find Due Payments report under the print menu.However, this report is not ordered using any column/field. The view of the report looks like:

```
 <tr t-foreach="Lines[o.id][currency]" t-as="line">
     <t t-set="invoice" t-value="env['account.invoice'].search([('number','=',line['move_id'])])"/>
       <td>
              <span t-esc="line['move_id']"/>
        </td>
        <td>
            <span t-esc="line['date']"/>
        </td>
```

I have tried sorting this report by changing the first line code as below..

```
 <tr t-foreach="Lines[o.id][currency].sorted(key=lambda x: x.date)" t-as="line">
```

but I get the error:AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'sorted'

I expect to sort the report by date or due date.